# How to check if optional flag is passed?

Tags: bash, shell

How to check if a specific option is specified by the user starting my bash script?

Example 1:

```
./script -a -b <param1> <param2>
```

Example 2:

```
./script -a <param1> <param2>
```

Example 3:

```
./script -b <param1> <param2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the built-in `getopts` for simple argument parsing:

```
a=0
b=0

while getopts ':ab' opt; do
  case ${opt} in
    a) a=1
    b) b=1
  esac
done

shift "$((OPTIND-1))"
```